# Accessing Highcharts when used with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm wanting to add some data to a Highchart that already exists on the page with:

```
window['chart_' + skill_id].series[0].addPoint(data, true, false);
```

This works fine if I created the chart with:

```
window['chart_' + skill_id] = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

But if I used jQuery instead like so:

```
window['chart_' + skill_id] = $('#' + skill_id).highcharts(options);
```

Then the global variable is no longer a reference to the chart but the jquery object itself and therefore I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` for the `series[0]`

How can I access Highcharts that are created using jQuery? The reason I want to use jQuery to create the charts is because I don't have to specify `renderTo` in the `options` and can keep this variable generic and just use jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [src](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/parts/JQueryAdapter.js#L138) you can see this line:

```
// When called without parameters or with the return argument, get a predefined chart
if (options === UNDEFINED) {
  ret = charts[attr(this[0], 'data-highcharts-chart')];
}
```

Which makes me this this would work:

```
window['chart_' + skill_id] = $('#' + skill_id).highcharts(options).highcharts();
```

The first call generates the highchart and returns the jquery object, while the second (chained) call without arguments is returning the generated highchart.

Comment: Perfect that gives me access :) Thanks!